# Play RTMP video streaming on android videoview

Tags: android

I just wanna play an rtmp video streaming in android videoview or android default player.ex "rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/osmf/content/test/akamai_10_year_f8_512K
".How could i do tht?Examples are much better..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at the Mplayer done by this guy

https://github.com/ajeet17181/mplayer-android

he gave support for RTMP also

Answer (score 0):

jwplayer supports rtmp. visit

http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/24717/jw-player-59-html5-now-default-on-android

its now default for android.

Comment: html5 is default, so that means no rtmp. HTML5 video is inferior to flash video in many ways.