# how to play RTMP video in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, rtmp

I have problem in playing RTMP video in ANDROID. pl, help me to overcome this problem. `rtmp://linux1-hkg.YYY.com:443/XXXXX"+"BacNew1Grand.stream`
this is the URL to hit the video.

Also i have referred this link [Play RTMP video streaming on android videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555172/play-rtmp-video-streaming-on-android-videoview) but its not useful for me..

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out. It may help you.

https://github.com/mekya/Vitamio-with-librtmp